# Ответ 511 python requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, requests, response, termux

Тут такая проблема: ответ с моего устройства от гугла и циана 200, а с сервера(vps), ответ от циана 511, от гугла 200. В чём может быть проблема?

С моего устройства:

```
>>> import requests
>>> requests.get('https://www.cian.ru').status_code
200
>>> requests.get('https://google.com').status_code
200
```

С сервера:

```
>>> import requests
>>> requests.get('https://www.cian.ru').status_code
511
>>> requests.get('https://google.com').status_code
200
```

**Update**

Получение headers:

С устройства:

```
>>> requests.get('https://www.cian.ru').headers
{'Date': 'Thu, 20 Jan 2022 10:03:56 GMT', 'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8', 'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Vary': 'Accept-Encoding, Cookie, User-Agent', 'X-Version': '[frontend-entry][CD-129216][ee3ddbb6]', 'Set-Cookie': 'session_region_id=4777; Domain=.cian.ru; Path=/', 'ETag': 'W/"47198-x8u/lus0CN1TxIc+f4VSdGKEzPI"', 'X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies': 'none', 'Strict-Transport-Security': 'max-age=2592000', 'Content-Security-Policy': "default-src https:; child-src blob: https:; connect-src blob: https: wss:; form-action https:; frame-ancestors https: http://webvisor.com; media-src https:; object-src https:; img-src https: data: blob:; script-src https: data: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; style-src https: 'unsafe-inline'; font-src https: data:", 'Content-Encoding': 'gzip', 'Via': '1.1 google', 'Alt-Svc': 'h3=":443"; ma=86400, h3-29=":443"; ma=86400', 'CF-Cache-Status': 'DYNAMIC', 'Expect-CT': 'max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"', 'Server': 'cloudflare', 'CF-RAY': '6d0779cb49e0359b-DME'}
```

С сервера:

```
>>> requests.get('https://www.cian.ru').headers
{'Date': 'Thu, 20 Jan 2022 10:03:35 GMT', 'Content-Type': 'text/html', 'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies': 'none', 'Strict-Transport-Security': 'max-age=2592000', 'Via': '1.1 google', 'Alt-Svc': 'h3=":443"; ma=86400, h3-29=":443"; ma=86400', 'CF-Cache-Status': 'DYNAMIC', 'Expect-CT': 'max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"', 'Set-Cookie': '__cf_bm=FsDmVvnliqGAvbVlst0N9Cq27YRXp6JkJaLQwTWnlGM-1642673015-0-AdJnc6qU0iqqSbtwIZGt6q8zoEVFhoY75gaZDncRq2jgQANXOE+ZnAZ5rhTAfkucBoSTGPaNZh7+l03Dt/NgalM=; path=/; expires=Thu, 20-Jan-22 10:33:35 GMT; domain=.cian.ru; HttpOnly; Secure; SameSite=None', 'Server': 'cloudflare', 'CF-RAY': '6d0779482e704e97-FRA'}
```

**Update 2:**

Text с сервера:

```
>>> requests.get('https://www.cian.ru').text
'<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="ru"><head><meta charset="UTF-8" /><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" /><link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.cian.site/frontend/common-css/l/common.min.css" /><title>&#x41E;&#x448;&#x438;&#x431;&#x43A;&#x430; - &#x426;&#x438;&#x430;&#x43D;</title><style>body{height:100vh}.logo-image{width:386px;margin-bottom:52px}.container{height:auto;padding:80px;-ms-flex-positive:1;flex-grow:1;-ms-flex-negative:0;flex-shrink:0;background-size:84% auto}.info{width:100%;max-width:386px}.title{font-size:38px;line-height:46px;font-weight:700;color:#000;margin:0 0 16px}.cf-browser-verification.cf-im-under-attack,.hidden{display:none}.cferror_details{list-style-type:none}.cf-error-details{color:#737A8E}.cf-error-details h1{font-size:18px;line-height:24px;color:#737A8E;margin:0 0 32px}@media (max-width:546px){.container{background:0 0;padding:30px 16px 16px}.info{max-width:100%;margin:0 auto}.cf-error-details h1,.title{max-width:250px;text-align:center}.logo{text-align:center}.logo-image{width:180px;margin-bottom:25px}.title{margin:0 auto 16px;font-size:22px;line-height:28px}.cf-error-details h1{margin:0 auto 28px;font-size:16px;line-height:22px;font-weight:400}}</style><script src="https://cdn.cian.site/frontend/fonts/l/fonts.min.js" data-fonts-public-path="https://cdn.cian.site/frontend/fonts/"></script></head><body><section class="container"><header class="logo"><a href="https://cian.ru/"><img id="logo" class="logo-image" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,%2F9j%2F4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD%2F2wBDAAQDAwQDAwQEAwQFBAQFBgoHBgYGBg0JCggKDw0QEA8NDw4RExgUERIXEg4PFRwVFxkZGxsbEBQdHx0aHxgaGxr%2F2wBDAQQFBQYFBgwHBwwaEQ8RGhoaGhoaGhoaGhoaGhoaGhoaGhoaGhoaGhoaGhoaGhoaGhoaGhoaGhoaGhoaGhoaGhr%2FwgARCACUAYIDAREAAhEBAxEB%2F8QAHQABAAICAwEBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAgJBgcBBAUCA%2F%2FEABwBAQACAwEBAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAEBQMGBwIBCP%2FaAAwDAQACEAMQAAAAn8AAAcPnjTKrzpMDI6297HiQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAPl8jH1TmcYOuaf%2BOT5tPTPc0OG9eyCBegAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAa92PXa%2Bv0pymQXL%2BmbU1Syh72%2FlsheYZ5Wcj7J9PoAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA0V0DVIgdq5lYd%2BZ%2BvZNW3UHe%2Bcq%2BPsScXA%2Bvffz0AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAMMu4td36a4pufQPWaUd5GbrWuSS5L1KV%2FJdo5AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAI09R1aJHauXvnzYup7rO%2F8APnRPZifQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAB8fUMu4aDqbcKWen536vmlN95AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAD5w%2B9PN8xC4xZ5Q5gAAAOAcgAAA4ByAA%2BH0ADgHIAAAAB5MuBoPoPNJFc26loXoOiYncUkjeZ9CyGvvAOPiH%2B6ar7UnFKHRds%2Fbz74%2BIhbnqvpy4so9F3DjF7h1veo5p98SY0bcfr596vrHELeNT72bDKvRdv72HPhtjWRV2SmwSVHzrPFkprc7Y%2Bu7d9PUaNnocTuKiWGkbb6UeRyaGv6TVOy0UrNK2rI4E4AD8fWGEXeuRaa3umltxO80xvkjWm161Yd%2BaOq5tSbQBxjUz3MXZu2Q7QNDse5iy%2FPhThbR853mptK5zc%2FnDz0v7DB39uVXZjzS%2B%2B%2FPqEF%2FVwVze9pbLEtd0G18jx6qZ2eoxaBZ5jVWuLWVXk236zaNqvnZeubfVrY%2BNdbTBtv1OVkMGQIA5ccSt0hW0UkjZdDJAHy8xO7Dy2MvWtZ5%2BO7Gx9jFk6WbxYd%2BaOq5tSbQBxjUz3MXZu2Q7QNDse5iy%2FPhThbR853mptK5zc%2FnDz0v7DB39udXZjzO%2B09PiVUWsfpec20tlhWt6Fa6Zp58Rc%2BSU8eXI73U6chzaot6opq7BUzw53slWtj411tMG2%2FU5WQwZAgBlxxL3SFbRSSNl0MkAaB6HoENO66J8evvcjzOlJhcfHbj%2BbDfzR1TNqTaAOMame5i7N2yHaBodj3MWX58KcLaPnO81NpXObn84eel%2FYYO%2Ftzq7E%2Bc3VT%2BwV%2FerLzmN8%2FPfdetc0K19SJ6ivtOvR4t4Xi58HTwZdJ0Wyyzt8dieiWdWtj409s9XKOx1zuYcg0LQbDgdrltopJGy6GSBqbbtNgx%2BhObdOR62dp2%2By74xusDv0Vxbxp0Xs4PthH5p6tndFsfIPjH8pjvIuztk8Wi6RL7mL38Y1NV1Fz3b4lp3P7LrRPdL%2Bxwt%2FbXCyDXPsbI1xaZr02v20heNulZbDo8%2BH9jWwSkytj0lzs2skdXNgjps9HK%2Bz92L6RLqvtYuip3zu4ZXPz6OnnhenaLaqKTselyjWuy6bBD9E8z8ubkz7Vt%2Bnf%2BfOgZBAx6R3rToS9%2B5t%2BXtu7nW8zT4dvvcxZBi0ZTVtNdv8A260s25q7OPxjUb7TVtFbvbbbOzvm7XkPxUJtdf7lt882qk2DwNilhRU9Ot3DyreJNqHN5FRNpUdvarC17QpWR442hptLVhbyZtbHaTr5n4qGtoLcZlpHL7P1Yvh8VkX9Zr%2Ff8drGrWOfUcf8vWKAf6K4vrLb4WR0%2B0zu%2FPXVc9ocY4fItda51FjsGl%2Ft4kzQ4H2Pe%2BiThicT3TbtVZnm3wN7RKb6%2BfPEgy4v117n%2B1Qpe%2BPO9%2BV7HUVttXx69SixbJYvR1vZh%2BadbqHl%2FQM9p3MZVY3yJqXo1dNn3R%2FvTfYZxLLCcc%2Bb202M6OWqgbKL3%2Bh%2BrXOcSvVjeOPKrCZH150Dzapqdjn9DgGNWcOGncdH39zLoO8dI9cvoH5%2FccRez6L94NkljyK87WPyOjC91B3X3G5fkADzZMLce6Y7MOPWVSF989uVJtHr2dQ4n54ftWGbL19%2Fx2j6R5xLXpNc15809d1%2F18977obrXc2DIbccM%2BuffKuMmfFd9w2r6X59yN948q9cWbQ3QY9odB72DSfAPz%2Bufj7AAPj6H38AcfPnQrpH5fMgAPla9zCw3fK62LQbD8qiZ9e%2FnfsI%2FL6OjX5vz8%2BvRsY3P37%2BUf1jsGXz9ZFYQupEz8%2BvnenYejBzfji9%2BnYxufQdSHk6uDN6dhF%2BvYAAAAAAAAAARzq5%2BP2nyU%2FqB%2Bvn6AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAP%2FEADIQAAAGAgEBBQcEAwEBAAAAAAECAwQFBgAHCDYQERIWNxMUFSAxNDUYITNQMDJBQGD%2F2gAIAQEAAQgA%2FwAEnbIaIA%2FvzTY9beKARBq9bPSeNp%2FWCIAAiO8N%2FnZKrQNNeTslILHWeEknifeJNcbllIF%2Bik%2FqdnbWeNTctv6vdNrPUNfyjxBRRR45Oc%2BqOPhLS0JIzdi4x1SSjfZRVqrbyozzuIkuOFsWV7mrko94AP8AV8qE1h18mdKqEaHn2RZOiGbfAESM85PLs19i9zLjo8URsi7YEv4if1e06iF2pEpFA6bLRj5VBXXG%2B3VWSI3f2flUIsDoQMjIupd8q7fcZqasK60i5AO4O7%2Bs5D6XJIoOLTXe4QEQHNV66c3SaInlZrzWsxDdgx%2FrFEiLJmTV5C6eGrPjz8DTao6tMsi0ba7oTKkRBEW39dKRjWZj3DGQpGqYSiOF1oj%2FAA%2Fv%2Fi%2Ff5u%2F5v3%2Fy2KwsavEuJKVp3IUZ%2B1O0XTN4k%2BbkXbbM5BrUm1OIdBHlU8WWImFQnVp2OFdz8lt5qoQFifxiWtuVp7%2FNe5ptlgcN01Q7LlzRQrdnkYlLXfLE98mfckWS%2FvTRFbHzoGLFy6NMc4UWEs%2BaE1hyfPsN6oQhDeIoD2SD9vFsnDx7YecsY1mHiEPSeYJrlOJxqEQ%2B%2BJRyDocv2z61rhgLqz2rniikc4VlbnBY1lhONa5ui6fESlKJuOCuqIGQIYpygYmbn5VNtX3Retkq3M4LNOtIskBIDKw7N4YOzfXIRPTj%2BMaDFc3QlH6DQKXZQtMQD0PlcOUmiJ1nO%2BNvrXaXPFxLV0qzXIu20btYHzdFm%2F5DHA%2BzpMwR33yGa0%2FDrfIP0HNqeoVgzi91BIZFfjWnYb6Dm4fUuyZxk6tWyG%2FFNMsXT8rlr6pm84pffu8R%2FiL2czt%2BAimegVXNA9dlypdPMc2dsCO1lTZGwzGx9lzmzLC5lp9lHupFYqLNppy6PkfbNJaCkoBcEZWgbDkqfLILI6evSNurbNQmczPX2w5qD1Bh8o3SUR28%2FwDqOs5WvzbPNHdEI%2FKYwEKYx%2BRG5gfHWq9d%2BvZEyzmGeEdMrDPObJJqPnsd98hmtPw63yD9BzanqFYM4vdQSGRX41p2G%2Bg5uH1LsmcZOrVshvxTTLF0%2FK5a%2BqZvOKX37vEf4i5yJ3OhqKlLuWkrKvZ6SXfyYlEg9xtA9dkyp9PsM5U64s%2B0KrHwtVDhdsL%2FALx345Ia%2BZ%2B%2F2gqCJS%2BEvIfUkNf6BLqLKpmQWUTNw4tK6qCMb2czPX2w5qD1Bh8o3SUR28%2F%2BpKxla%2FNs80d0Qj8vIHcSdZYLV%2BDXWUcqnVXABEe4HcS9YIIru%2ByO%2B%2BRzWn4db5B%2Bg5tT1CsGcXuoJDIr8a07DfQc3D6l2TOMnVq2Q34ppli6flctfVM3nFL793lrtsZR6w9nJ7d203e2r0%2Fml9Jarc7DszNAeQ1YaU%2FYbmIj9A9dkypdPMccOEmqCiznaXNCu1hdaOqU3zMusocRQ%2FVjeslOUd6ko50zw6hlVDqKcMfyvZzM9fbDlOn%2FACxYmcoMVzYfxDFFmz%2FXVL5%2BuuWzdW6pPccq0dSta%2FNs80d0Qj8m3dxRlIiHbZjKyrqZfrvZAA7x7g1XqyQuMqkY89qWFmKR5cy1V5erTz2Kd5HiBXqIjq50k5hlTIdpxAhDCOyXiL%2B9TrhpxjXSQsq6SsWAhHNAHDiBSGE21XiD%2FYliXacaFSJXHwHiSiSMaAazrEb1uYVWsa6bqwSy7fisumlKLpH5gb6Jcn6NRqtVqz60SiDRjojVDbXdZQOvynlGkpuawiw0Qum2vCR16sQyUCyKpzV3iswBGkVQhFHCnhJTNGXC7LECKR4VXpUneM1w8uMFEPZJ%2BcvgOYucM1iEnEkBHOYblJ3vmxHQRQUXN4UQgZIQ7w%2BASefAJPF26rVQU3FXIZScZgTSaB0aQ2FTs21sxpSIdYiU%2FOOrDJrvXwZriivLTLJJkqdWZVaMI1Y5vbTKF3jjzEKu3VaLHRdZozai1ZliMpGMkUJVmk6admx11G1DsSreUETSLoR4sNUFrQUy0f8AYtuzYKyjejWJZCaMJ5Z6Y3FlsgtbEhWj%2FsW%2Bb%2FXWa6gtCjZX%2BVTI21PoVACRMcwXlnxEG%2FFXTisMghNyrj9myubl9VrnnHdqi5uiBV4wwkgEjE3M%2FdyWzLStIaigmsvMj79R4ZjC1pghGZywvyNR1PMtUDG8RjDnD5BP3%2BEw3%2Bps3%2BsovtiyHX0vFtZGcWF7WKTAFrsSA%2BSa%2Fg0qAzlg0QZ7hnEWmsUU1rO2BXTQiOvokRxcFDIKghuxSwBcHydkyoVtewyzZslrbXrGnRSHs%2B3kTpT7m21rGpVTLF9hx5dTpogE5Hs2b6e2TJP79zmrtmhrt6d2QnOSdTIBCfrnnstXNKzzsI%2Bi0HC5nK6ix9X7JDXj8zsuqOT87cH7ZtnIMe%2FTNnxX%2BVTClE49xeMWovM0uiutERaELHN2LN19urm5vVe5Zxx61QyFDxQ7YM5b0NzT9oPHg0yx%2BXZZByejcyIqKg2rSYsfOuFaAdOJ2VtKe2hOnlbFnD77%2BFw%2F%2Bhs336qWPNFfmnWVvp2L7P8Ag5y59aJ4M1b1Q2zTHp7Edt0o8Re4dWNntm6KlqNKE%2BG6I1weDiwkZP5FUiLpHSV3loI8MdWeqOnNGPHy5H8%2BwYoxzYiDbsmI5KWjHTF1f9cTUJcJdi18nT%2BeTp%2FPJ0%2Fnk6fzydP49j3cat7F%2FwAeZdZCyotkrbDJWmhyUc8n6BOxk7Js09ca6l5azIIvdV0clGrRGZsVL40jlzkfq2ZgtqTazLRUZKQtxbne172vwZoDjaup4TasCpFz22eM1r11JLe4LQki3OKayEDJuh8KGouK1jvD0PjmyNRTlJuMpDNuI68m0sTNg8MHeUc5Qa2lonbs0MbqtnMV6xJe%2BU86itYijL5%2Fwc5pawdIXNCehNfQEzG2Nqo500i6b0aPRe9qqKa5BIuQhUyARP5TpkVIJVU0iIk8KPyLwka6P43XlqHzy1D55ah88tQ%2BeWofOaTVBnt4UmnHrrYcjA745ABVgYxwoKi7aEjmantGodrqIYPTAZ4jARaChVEAAA7FW6S5BKsrryrrHMdVtr%2BrtFAUQTSTRJ4UnMNHvD%2BN20iGDE4qMsdRDB8fxvC1yIIYDFAAAO4Ox3HNH4AD0K3EFHvApQIHcX%2Fzbq4sMNt2Yk4pr7hqypM8EljdEG6JEi%2F%2FABX%2FxABHEAACAQMABQYJCAgFBQAAAAABAgMABBEFEBIxURMhQVNUsSAiUmFxobLC0RQyUGORk5SzIzM0VXJzgbQVJDCSwUBgotLi%2F9oACAEBAAk%2FAP8AQ0jbRlN6mUbQ%2FpWkoSScc5xU8cycUYH6NOAKmIlQgT3Qx9gq%2Bnlkc5YtIaupl9Ehq6keAtTAsVUsPT9GHE8qGCI8GYEA0S0kjZPnJqV47XIIAwCeIoS2F2N0qGhs3Fs2DXOLcxxL6DkfRn6lLgCSs%2FJS%2Fj7O%2BtkKhwcdJ1CLbS1VZyhBy%2B0%2B%2BoGeOdoSZehCpbvzXkj6LGZ2iLwfzQDs%2BusxzQOVPpFAzDcSQMVagXLpgTEfMNStPcSnLMemkBgBjbec5Gfo2JzeJg3UKAHbG7IFDVFIYU52wKTZSJAPo1Q6MMEEZBqDGipzmZEQ4hbNRO4dseKpNRKLlx%2Bkf6PiE1tcIUkU9INCQtKzHxyDgE5xu%2BjZ0hghXPjuFydwAzRS3tGucQIZM5i2jj1U6yI45ipzVoHEA3mrKPL0gSRW2Tj0A%2BDowEWsmxkzY92rFIIEK8rIH2yM1udQ3269Ggi0k2MmbHu1YxwouNs8rmhjlEDY9NDKwRNIR6ATWi0xBO8QzPwYjyaskhij4SZJNdI1SrDbwIXkdiAABVgk9nDKyRzGf9YAd%2B6rCOHI22flaXY5VQ2M51aSt7UkZSFplDv6ATmtDh%2F5k3%2FzVlseZJyKghETdJk2KnggJVSMzqd9EMp3EarITzWyIZXMvlorjoqxSAzlhth9vcpO7Fb54lf7QDrsxcm8R2yXxuxWj4YjK2MtPQAGQuRubz%2BE4jiQZZjuFSumhbbAAwByj5JJpzHKhBUipsPziRWrcR7zV5YrrfdXwe0%2B6K4wd711Kd2vtXuivq%2FerqV7q7JL7Brt8%2F5jV1nwrhqvJRMcHSrxhcYySI9reDkKdXUH20rqhT4S3Q8lH0yyYJCDznFXkkxc%2Fo4uYKi9AAGBULzSOwUBR0k4FaEuJY%2BIFWstrIRtKGGMirmUwB12k38wPnov40ZKF8ccHV1Vp%2FbR1xk%2FKeuyRewuvqJvcrrBXEd3gkKqjJJqUGCNx8pmXPOcbtb7EiUcyMMegV5YrrfdXwe0%2B6K4wd711Kd2vtXuivq%2FerqV7q7JL7Brt8%2F5jV1nwrhTwy6busw2cJfnVipw5Uc5UGp5Lu8uG2pJGOSxoEGuzn20rqhQhMAueWnD78gEDGWFRQ%2Fan%2FvUCSaTIXYQlTs4pVAqBRpKxtGmtpgBldg7ZFZDIxU%2BkGtyXT%2Bzq6q0%2Fto64yflPXZIvYXX1M3uV1griO7wZs6UuYyJZEfBhFMZJHOWZjkk6raSKGcZjdlIDbt32jX5YrrfdXwe0%2B6K4wd711Kd2vtXuivq%2FerqV7q7JL7Brt8%2F5jV1nwq5S2s7SIuWdgNo9CjPSTgChJFZhzHaQGUsEQYUEDcCQoJoERO5x58Amokijtogh2BgMwJBNdnPtpXVCnWKGMFndjgAUg0rcjfOCpQGj8k%2FlvV%2FP%2BJatJToJ4zGTy7HmPMaYu7ksxO8k12xvy9XVWn9tHUfK%2FJy3i8cqV%2F5q0%2FQxABcgGrX%2FwAFq19S1DHClmGWEJwOK6wVxHd4FwJtMthEjA%2BYTz5NSma4mYs7HiTqiKWivh39AzUAQRQbMEvSrhcBqOZLZ8ZHSCAR6jq3BxTh1MmQR6B4BwAKkEsL3J2WHmAFPh7h4ViHlEFq3iFB6tW4CpBLC12QG9AANHDTNGsfnPPW8RL3UwWNLOUseA2DTh4pbyZ0bipckGnw7vlfVV6JdB2iZvHQfrptvcc8NlTVvJMHYbWxjOM1bCDSkyHlV37FTiYQTyQS%2BZ1kbIpthGiKA%2BfaWhgiMVpEJLKHOldgHbA3BKBd2NaMdo3QPtkgAAjIrkE9L1NbJBaQtLIdvoFHODjNHEst07IOI2NThwEtR9lvHS7bVZTEfw1Yz%2F7KsZ%2F9lRtE43hhihk8oKGNvBH2DXOn%2BISKQqh%2BdRipDI8jard3iyDIwX5oz31Eikb2CBdUQi05AASEj%2FaF4GonhmQ4ZHUqynzg6rj%2FACkmR45qRZI5FB5jnXI0UqWMpV0OCDsmjkmQ5NQo5QqVJFdWvdqdo5U0dOyupwQQhoksZmJJ9NRI5RwVJFdWvdUrwyCBBtIcHBlQGvKPfU8tpJuaSFyjEcMio2kkkYDCLmrE22EBUSDnd88zV5Jr98XX5rVEkw4OM9IrnZYMj7KmkmmGlrtAZCSVUTMAvoFEGNSuU2ec%2BMNzdFIEi5FCd2SdkarmAaVv0SKCF3GSplUPhf4Nquk5pBzQyuP4tthqdpH%2BVEZaoUnEexsq4BHO2K0VaMfkcOS0Kkk7A5zzVoiz%2B4X4Vomz%2B4X4VCkMSCABU%2FlikVwNrf8AwmjkmFPZGohZSp2CdwPRUcsI5Z%2BRzudQfnDzHVGW5WQD0DpP9BSI1w6Alhk%2BAiIAC99B766siToIoGW2KJh2O4YOPt1%2Fu%2BX2TXWGoZJZTjZwFI5s8TUL%2FcxUj%2FcxUmEvYJIJHeKPmDDFfOc5NRSyy82zshf%2BTUI%2BTcskJDhBXURfnJXlHvrfU0Zic5lwudgAZoFYYECjJJ3V5Jr98XX5rVw95a6YxX7Fpd3uYH85OX9bUXEaNkhOmoZZ3jQDbAStG3Mrnc4CH3qunckBY4dyRLknAAwOk8%2Brs8vttXCu1tX1Xtiuxw%2BwNf1P5Yrg%2FsmuoT2BrgMiMpCSLgPESMbS5BGRSTaR0VMQI5uZmU8GxjuqERzyEEJ4IDxupVgekGkuLqCeVnuoWdDyZPP4oABxUPIQQtzISPHNDCINcYlguIzG6HcwIrRN80EU%2FiEx5yCM7wMVoe8%2B5NaIvPuTWiLz7k1oi8%2B5NaHvPuTVvJbS4zsyLg4pUOGE5zxUgDvqLl0urQgpxI5x6wK0RfFLe6liQtESSFcgHIrQ92YlG0QYjSBLmRtuUAggHAGBjo1dIxVhd3VrpG5lukkAD87OSRzVo26iyMJm3c5baHAUmxJyY2hUTkb0kiIDo2CMqSCKsZ9K6J3pOhR2%2FqB8KsblXG8ckasLhzwEZq2fRlgHYTO%2BAwAXIxWjry6tYJ2EEwjztpk45wMVYzQPAjhcwOPEJJyTu1aOvbmyuSk0UuA%2BSUUtu4E1ou6it7h1V3Ns7EY5xjHnxSlH%2BSRZBBGPEGu1vr19J%2FtW5kQoFChQBWi7uNCWGTA3SpqJoHSJAFYYONkeBGkiHerqCKUKoGAAMDwkDqd4YZFIqLwUYHg2NtM%2FF4VY%2BsVouz%2FDr8K0XZ%2Fh1%2BFaLs%2Fw6%2FCtF2f4dfhWi7P8OnwqFIIxYpzJ%2FHJXUH21rdsVo%2B1lc72aFSasbaGTdtJCqn1DwLOCdhuMkQbvrR1rHIpyrLAoI9WuNZFPQwzWgdGs7HJJtIyT6q0Do1ZF3MLSPI9VIqLwUYqyt524yRBu%2BrO3gcjBaOIKSP6arOCdx0yRBj660bZhgcgiBfh4FtFcAHmEiBu%2BtGWYI4QL8KAAH%2FT6QeynEQietMyzJsFClbkGB%2F2X%2F8QALxEAAgICAQIEBQQBBQAAAAAAAgMBBAAFEQYQEhMzNBQVIDEyISI1UEEWJDBAYP%2FaAAgBAgEBCAD%2FAIE0rD5%2FYequLjkjWYTwX9b0z0pD4i1cVTrpGBCUKn77nptFhckm7TOmyQL%2Br6doxf2S1kMCsOI3nVzKjJUin1psUN8TNfdXsawvX1fQEDkx%2Fq%2Bh5D5lMTsZYNQ5VsYOHz4s6IBgayZLrABKsJ5P3%2Fq9JfnW31vxZi9cFG46TG5Mmqj0LMs5ehC6y4WvrLZAcwoP6zpLqOUGNKx23%2B5DXImBt2jtuJh%2F1kTIzzHSXUXxgxUftdkvXpkp2mybsXSRf1yXHXZDF7Hd2tnEQ7%2BsqVW3HQpWx6TmnUEoMCWUiWl6UjaVIfh9DwAyU3qw1mcD3meI5yhq9XarA0n6KiKZNJD4Ske0zxHOa%2FV6u1VFpu0NKEkxBj4DkcmYGOSrajVOQDJtaKotPmI%2B3ZYEwoEUaPXwEecWgoSsiS9flMkO1PXvuz%2BwdTrUBy0F6YB4z5HqbH6I2Gjs0c447anXULiPMcWi10hMqsKhLSCO2nqUb3jh4dP61s%2BFd2tFVvgj6QAmF4R6V6eHXJ89zFg0JA%2BpdFKDkw6OjjUjln0SzberH0M%2FCc1%2FtQyn7csd6pdj%2FCc1vtAzW%2Bwfj%2FVLHenOVfbhiP4mcn79qlfyF%2BaWaX8H5c9csrJ89kDLH8jC1mwFxyZ7miE8Eiyt8eJWt2fP%2B3s7vXzUeU9tb6Oa31Cy%2FwC5PvrfXbmr9xm69z9MRz%2BkdIdOSMRdsdrNZdpcrOjTCinygs%2BiWbb1Y%2Bhn4Tmv9qGUvbljvVLsf4Tmt9oGa32D8f6pY705yr7cMR%2FEzk%2FfKVfzC8ZkXMyUxMTml%2FB%2BXPXLDvfBOiS%2F1CrGQGxmGFFRERxHkTRcL64z9pjYH8TRE5zW%2Bjmt9Qsv%2B5PvrfXbmr9xm69z9PSfTxXmxacACsYEcVZS4iAO1n0SzberH0M%2FCc1%2FtQyl7csd6pdj%2FCc1vtAzW%2Bwfj%2FVLHenOVfbhiP4mcUkntgB%2FQBhQ32yhUZqiIkz4tL%2BD8ueuWCEsmBitpKyogrqT09ceI%2BN1WPta1ipEIjjD%2FjZ7a30c1zlJdy1tTRuOTL5foM%2BXaHGVK1ewZVtX7jN17n6NBoH7N4kVauuqqFLzfb5NBMiFTeWat%2F4uKFwb1YXjj4mVFEbgZFsc92T%2BycohIVhgqjQhJDLvULsyeAnKAEFYRKg9YU3BLp5YWO9OcrjIoAZQ5c62VQpE1BmCdYUiOWEXmzLJ1iyBHJal61Q2Dtzy8soiVfkyIv8AJWNxVr%2Fpk9RD%2FivuysthQRPMc4TQnXkPaio1K8JzMDHM%2FEJz4lOfEpwSE45HXGIP5LcFB2OY7aLUM2T4ylUXTTC15u9qukmeLtxlxsmedL9RHrGwhoGLB8Q51RohtKlymqJJyBdnmSw8QqnkIxSVRriOGfnPZ5ksPEKZ5XEylCvl5Mxn5zjTNcjID9ow7KhT4VEX%2BZurTAcE%2BeFFxrZkqSpnXoUVQzm8XhI5ykcmgZmjrIuLkpela3l4MqJZJ%2BdERxGbJCg1XiFs8LnNYZMrQR62ki4BQ21qanxDM%2BU1MnU1Yic0oQutAjp1Awp8W8EQvGI4HEFHi6YGl8FE1s2d4aaCLNttG32zz36R6kmJijZxkhAz4%2BqQqw%2BZV2telOK9OMpX6MVpr2JraCZ5n4Xp%2FLlXTyuRSI%2BGOMo7CkNaUWH6bWvQTkWf0kcH7R2kpCPNJrJaclNn0SzV%2ByVmt9keXR8ZGOaR8GklTp76q5eB9zp2tbZLkFpKlUolxkM8CGbX%2BIxvplmp9rGaP8Dy17g%2BxfjOan0M0n5Tm%2B%2FkGd9bsrGrfDkaXqmvskz5vUe3m06Vh9AzIzzHTHVcPiKtzqDqcOJUhjCaUkXa4BmgoClsEMriR%2FG1s%2BNrZ8bWz42tnxtbFsBschQaB0iEtkJQMyCL9c0iUhb15%2FtbZaLC4DHDJLmI1F5cVoU3XbbXhVNZ2eJcXD67lPizVpbpTv2PF6ijmCsJD72twM8hWpbNTkQTbezo2dZ5YHHiCYjVW1LR5bdNtaKvEB2iA3EQZMcxMZq7YpM0u0201yWTD901T7ZMV3EpGeYmZmeZ%2BmJmJ5iSkv1n6J11Up5n5ZUz5ZUz5ZUz5ZUz5ZUzTLFSjEdd6J4%2BIIyiZ1tWZxdCsueR7soVml4iHW1RnmOza6nR%2B%2F5WjjiB1qI%2B61AuOAPX1mTySaSEF4gxlGu0vEca2rE4MQMcR2bTQ%2BeT%2BWVMABWPhH%2FrA2%2FUIoVV3O2SXEkXimZn%2FwAV%2F8QANhEAAQIDBQQJBAEFAQAAAAAAAQARAhAhAzFBUbEgYXGBEiJQUpGhweHwBDAy0YIjQEJg8fL%2F2gAIAQIBCT8A%2BxATyUBQbs4UwCgAA3KEeChr2bc7lXBAIiIZFXFf5OezL2or2ncTTwCNQ9M3bsy568MVUGUVAgwCNQ47NPVNxymalY9nHri45o1Rp2eWIWHZoclVLV4oKK9RXK7Zt2Jwb3Vr0jw9zsW7E4Nv4q16TbvdYK5fUM4BuGI4q0MQzams7yvqB0sWb9q16RG73KwkGGZu8VbGKLID3KhKtq72Hqg44TtuicvhVt0iMPhWBna9Awt58wrdzy%2Fe2HKH9Q%2BQQcFDgs1kstvOe%2FUrdqs5ZDRd70M%2FyN24S7p1ErseCHRhFwHxyio1E660JpPM6yzM932BwExSWSy28579St2qzlkNF3vQyHVHnun3fUShJDYKzPn%2Bk7ZYKAKlQCMC9JYBvOWZ1lmZ7tsdQeaDASiBIvnkstvOe%2FUrdqs5ZDRd70KxVwWKL1K7vqJByo23Cp53MrHpcV9KPnJfTAGXysszqrio4n4e6ji8PdRxeHuiWO0Gs8SgwEj1kbzVY%2FZNVnO%2F3RqWWcsANEet0ruS%2FI37giyLjBC8uOCLEw08RKFiWYoouVZFWJc8P3I1EgxlEFEFEEdkdVBmlFVGRezPki4Moa7BYyhD0rMsZCtJFi8g0WcgIicxdLujRQ1Y15yL0GkoAOAaRYQ%2Bb0bk7yhAMi5Qe%2FRDE6oIK5zqg6DAGVyIJYPukUabFe6ZXKmyIqtc37C6Xz%2BSEXz%2BShiJOf8A6MhFXJv2E4LE1%2F6VnOGgunkNFkdZXwFl%2BKtgAasX91bCLcPgQaEXCWayW%2FUrfoszrPM6yzOszXyO4oiGMYIuNogEChr5o7F6jAKjCjCjCjCjHii4RwIWBGqjDkBWrPl%2FwovDMiEw08FagFvVFfliM11I1EFEFWLChZRARXEbxerQGJ7pRARAmnMsrUAl9EXBLzIDXc1agAouDjsH7sKhUKhUKhVwJnCoRsQqGcIKccynPMoMoVCxlDVQ7ELqBXf24BBL1UELH%2FTP%2F8QALhEAAgIBAgQGAgICAwEAAAAAAQMCBAAFERASMTIGExQgITMVUCJCNEEjMEBg%2F9oACAEDAQEIAP8AosatRq7%2BYrxHprZcoTYVYHMv9Z0zWtdlaka9XkiTuSuBxD7GnzDEaRqi9TQJj9Xr9iSKEuVcDMiI0zQ6cFczrGi0Hw5RdqSpPKpaC%2F0t8DB8%2Fq%2FEi5yqgiL51pBkNHtQt1ROOeIbULF0xjpVQtfF2Dp%2BrtVxaRNJemSWSXOhet6VMlDfE996zCMY%2FwCs0XTiiuJT%2FWa7pQuw85ZBB2OaFo5aQ920Y9v6wfGeINJA3tJ0bSpXm7yjGC4CEP13x0KkJTHlX%2Bsu3VUEFrFeJbcLfO1D4WFhi9Y1rUKdsqUfEuqgZo91t6sGs9luesRfIKS3V4nmdCXNEHjcnrEXyCYP1mEx5iyZQBOxPR7NaDZCCbGrwYPNHBkwuBkW2tXdLnT5%2BtxIMkTlNYlLLeoLqnkBbq9k%2FE6OqTO%2BSdr1Yc50%2FwARqsMKbAIkNxmpnUoTj6UN13fK5nJQM%2BGpS1CHL6WT9dgN8pzaxQLfa1sEwM56rqbNTfvkoiY2Og6tLT3eQ3xARK8SJdDnhv8AwR7Bj%2FsON%2BqWK%2BscBlj7TljvjiuwZHrjO%2BWN%2B7I9OBbNrCOFn%2BuI%2BsZMkRPLXrRTvIprtsHZY0S1j6rq52ZqelKvKO3h6%2FJkDVblntjhxH1ji7tHBH9vaSIgk67q5vMKFcGLDBsd5kDnl0OeG%2F8ABHsGP%2Bw436pYr6xwGWPtOWO%2BOK7BkeuM75Y37sj0x7Rv5OKVBMBBZBHWz%2FXEfWMVXW%2BJ5vxqcbajWV5CPMOJsc8CmcomJMTGiqFv1Iyz2xw4j6xxd2Dgj%2B3t8Qaz1poGAEnYNpWEQDJ8JdDnhv8AwR7Bj%2FsON%2BqWK%2BscBlj7TljvjiuwZHrjO%2BWN%2B7JzMIbhUZiO7KCQN3T1MiTxIWf64j6xjGwTAzm25etbxqs0y2%2F7fwTMTo01MEzh6jhZ7Y4%2BLZLIVBGuLGw5Nezk17K5eERg%2FEf29ms68lEZIR89SAT8DRNCaJee96F2UlLbSoofJccEJM%2FjHQFTRUEGexshKZINZrlS5IRMIiJ4OkJzJE6rnyiVwiYxAIIB3MyJTJD1Thu%2BSLEbkQ0VKbbJ3i9pP%2FGL04zZHlnXa%2Fby1wkuHLJvk3PkLXJkhGC9IbyiTvxtPH06CFmciAD8Cu2URMZOwqxCJUtU2nlh%2BPtZ%2BPtZ%2BPtZOEly5ZRhKZ2jBU0kifDxDrIpr9OmEOUbnPD2ilh89057%2FAzXNGjZibCeGj6qT%2FCcJhkdxwEIs%2FjIDb4FKcumT7jwjCM%2F4y2A%2BBSlLpk%2B45yQYDGY6YwlyilldJdMRDXeQnyox6437JZTlISIDPlhwqgqcowpM8uZOWWzawmWX3JbKNOWV5y8jbBk1QTMxXSbNTCYzv2eY56%2BzgvWctsm1nNNBInjiTIE4wTKyIXqNmtYlOzmhaTK60Tn8LgFw465ooSTZRlZbWNAVRqsSkSbwX3cLXr%2BXama%2BvH5PpteyqjVoMEnZZ9fy7U9Mq6lNhNqPwTg6YASdghUaijPGTLJGRj1xv2zyp3nGfDDlmBEufGFsQSmWpaquZAFvWbMSIVagrgmWV%2FpwZY%2B05W7zk%2B48X94xHfjeo42qibiytt3w1NTImtWX6RAUPZOEWRMJX%2FDAhDnp6PpcNPWJMlIzO54LIEgTLTbPMeT8Zcz8bbz8bbz8bbz8bcxqGIlysW6SCSEHnI3OmWtyI1qNpU%2BaVl4fL4yPXGUHMlzpFO8g7x3nL5nBgMCqbNNM489eVZ8CQV07DTtFVFNVZlZbprTPdHkXK8dpDGUHO2YoUriDzZ%2FPcifCVNlgCap0b6RzwJbvsziCR09wO2bk%2B2Fh0BtH1djPV2M9XYz1djPV2MtsmyQM5f7xfaMjZdAbCdhzBtLjB7V9hsvkNjwjKUT8C9Zw3rBwyJ6wsNWNoze1g2nkHtUNoereRt7INYvs9XYwnf%2FAM6pU5R2c0UDE8gAHwP%2FAIr%2FxAA4EQABAwEFBAgFAgcBAAAAAAABAAIRECExQVGRAxIgYQQiUHGBobHRMDKSwdJA8BMjM0JgguHx%2F9oACAEDAQk%2FAPgbQSMJtW01sTgRy7OMNF5z5BWoJxgYK%2FEdmXus1oN5y2e6cx%2F2aXO7MuF6vCvx76f22I%2FK5vjJ7MxCwVrcimhs440F8Hs0dceYqLMEI7OHeEOqELB2g2Ozf%2FV8hN2QlGQUBC3UIPDu7qIgRhwRu4LdjQ13Ykwt0jzrgmhrcAb%2FABujuW7GivoC52QtPeYuHNbuyH1fiulR3NP5KH8gI%2B5Tf4buZ9wKxHNbqvqBGMrdKEOx4jACsYLh9zQ9QrIff4vOuayqOoNZ9qZ0vRlxvKEqE2EIcLjzXzM%2BDnw3L%2BmDfmeAzFnxedc1lQwSChAGFM6P3T3LbDQo2Zoq0H1WC%2BY%2FBz4f9jlyq0gH4%2FOuayV6Mk%2FuPBCwIRLQVnQwBem7ozdf4DEeK6S7ws9Cukv%2Bo%2B66Q8xhvO96Z1dDsDetsNFtm6LbN0Tt5wvMRTPgM7S7uqIi6ULCjIFLyhB4mzPC2RbwDqAWnxQIGHMZoWBXDzRuaAhNqvRkNN2EhCSiGhbb96LbQB97BhmihZQyBI0KEpiYmIQUEIqf5jssOavNBZhKuoIeL7L62u9RwCQaGokGhoJFLWnDgzKNGx3Zmhmgkug2YQZBPIkRQ2UAA5c6PKedU86oyeC%2BLFa5xv8Aag6oVgHBdiOeYpejaQOHaBhzIn1BXSR9I%2FFdJH0j8V0mQCLA0W%2BQptA05kT6grpE8g0ew4L65mtxV62IIzk%2ByY1nMkzpulHecbzn7dws4OXHlUWLrNOcSPRCLOESCpJm0EjyuQ63C2R3hM9EzzCZ5hM8wmeiEFBYpkjvCZ5j3QgCo3gbcL1s9SPdC1XH9yjvDIkSPRMKYVbOATZaeYTIH21oJB7ls%2FT3Qg1E6LZye8e6EH9C4hPOpTzqU86lPOpTzqUZKyo4jxTifHgcQnnWpTynnWjiE4mjiE86ngMJ51P6hknkmGf8M%2F%2FZ" alt="logo"></a></header><article id="article" class="info"><h1 class="title">&#x422;&#x430;&#x430;&#x43A;, &#x447;&#x442;&#x43E;-&#x442;&#x43E; &#x441;&#x442;&#x440;&#x430;&#x43D;&#x438;&#x446;&#x430; &#x43D;&#x435; &#x437;&#x430;&#x433;&#x440;&#x443;&#x437;&#x438;&#x43B;&#x430;&#x441;&#x44C;...</h1></article><section class="snippet"><h2>&#x41C;&#x44B; &#x43E;&#x431;&#x43D;&#x430;&#x440;&#x443;&#x436;&#x438;&#x43B;&#x438; &#x43F;&#x43E;&#x434;&#x43E;&#x437;&#x440;&#x438;&#x442;&#x435;&#x43B;&#x44C;&#x43D;&#x44B;&#x439; &#x442;&#x440;&#x430;&#x444;&#x438;&#x43A;, &#x438;&#x441;&#x445;&#x43E;&#x434;&#x44F;&#x449;&#x438;&#x439; &#x438;&#x437; &#x432;&#x430;&#x448;&#x435;&#x439; &#x441;&#x435;&#x442;&#x438;.</h2><p>&#x41F;&#x440;&#x43E;&#x432;&#x435;&#x440;&#x44C;&#x442;&#x435; &#x43D;&#x430;&#x441;&#x442;&#x440;&#x43E;&#x439;&#x43A;&#x438; &#x432;&#x430;&#x448;&#x435;&#x439; &#x441;&#x435;&#x442;&#x438; &#x438; &#x43E;&#x442;&#x441;&#x443;&#x442;&#x441;&#x442;&#x432;&#x438;&#x435; &#x43F;&#x43E;&#x434;&#x43A;&#x43B;&#x44E;&#x447;&#x435;&#x43D;&#x438;&#x439; &#x441; &#x438;&#x441;&#x43F;&#x43E;&#x43B;&#x44C;&#x437;&#x43E;&#x432;&#x430;&#x43D;&#x438;&#x435;&#x43C; &#x440;&#x430;&#x437;&#x43B;&#x438;&#x447;&#x43D;&#x44B;&#x445; VPN, &#x430;&#x43D;&#x43E;&#x43D;&#x438;&#x43C;&#x430;&#x439;&#x437;&#x435;&#x440;&#x43E;&#x432;, &#x430; &#x442;&#x430;&#x43A; &#x436;&#x435; &#x447;&#x442;&#x43E; &#x43D;&#x435; &#x438;&#x441;&#x43F;&#x43E;&#x43B;&#x44C;&#x437;&#x443;&#x44E;&#x442;&#x441;&#x44F; &#x43F;&#x43E;&#x445;&#x43E;&#x436;&#x438;&#x435; &#x440;&#x430;&#x441;&#x448;&#x438;&#x440;&#x435;&#x43D;&#x438;&#x44F; &#x434;&#x43B;&#x44F; &#x431;&#x440;&#x430;&#x443;&#x437;&#x435;&#x440;&#x430;, &#x43A;&#x43E;&#x442;&#x43E;&#x440;&#x44B;&#x435; &#x43C;&#x430;&#x441;&#x43A;&#x438;&#x440;&#x443;&#x44E;&#x442; &#x432;&#x430;&#x448; &#x440;&#x435;&#x430;&#x43B;&#x44C;&#x43D;&#x44B;&#x439; IP &#x430;&#x434;&#x440;&#x435;&#x441;.</p><p>&#x415;&#x441;&#x43B;&#x438; &#x432;&#x44B; &#x441;&#x447;&#x438;&#x442;&#x430;&#x435;&#x442;&#x435; &#x44D;&#x442;&#x43E; &#x43E;&#x448;&#x438;&#x431;&#x43A;&#x43E;&#x439; - &#x43E;&#x442;&#x43F;&#x440;&#x430;&#x432;&#x44C;&#x442;&#x435; &#x441;&#x43B;&#x435;&#x434;&#x443;&#x44E;&#x449;&#x438;&#x439; ip-&#x430;&#x434;&#x440;&#x435;&#x441; &#x43D;&#x430; &#x43F;&#x43E;&#x447;&#x442;&#x443; <a href="mailto:support@cian.ru">support@cian.ru</a> &#x441; &#x43E;&#x43F;&#x438;&#x441;&#x430;&#x43D;&#x438;&#x435;&#x43C; &#x43F;&#x440;&#x43E;&#x431;&#x43B;&#x435;&#x43C;&#x44B;</p><iframe src="https://www.cian.ru/ip" style="border:none;background:0 0;max-height:60px"></iframe></section><script>function loadLogo(){var t=document.createElement("img");t.onload=function(){var t=document.getElementById("logo");t&&t.setAttribute("src","//cdn.cian.site/frontend/frontend-status-pages/logo_glitch.gif")},t.src="//cdn.cian.site/frontend/frontend-status-pages/logo_glitch.gif"}loadLogo()</script></section></body></html>\n'
```

Comment: А в теле ответа что-то при этом пишет?

Comment: Обновил вопрос.

Comment: @Boro8ey нужно не headers, а text или content

Comment: С устройства слишком большой ответ. Добавлю с сервера.

Comment: Обновил вопрос.

Comment: может разные user_agent ы передаются

Comment: Я думаю проблемы в днс

Comment: @Boro8ey вот так ответ с сервера выглядит, если положить в html файл и открыть: https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3m60.png Очевидно, циан что-то подозревает, и не хочет, чтобы данные с сайта обрабатывались ботом с vps)

Comment: А если подключить прокси?

Comment: Возможно циан блокирует все ip не из РФ, так что теоретически прокси может помочь, если он будет перенаправлять запрос так, как будто он из РФ, а не из рандомной страны.